# ODBC driver for MS Access seems missing (Windows 64 bit)

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc

I am simply trying to connect a java application to MS Access in the Eclipse IDE. From what I have read and done on other computers I need to go to the ODBC Data source administrator and add user DSN MS Access Database. The problem I have is that I recieve an error indicating that the ODBC Driver is not installed.

Now I assumed it would be as simple as downloading and installing it like say MySQL ODBC driver, this doesnt seem to be the case. From what I have read it is somthing to do with 32 and 64 bit windows 7 o.s.

I would appreciate if someone could identify the problem.

Thanks in advance

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this help?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/685eacc1-a670-42d4-8392-924230fa90cb

Comment: Thanks Smandoli, between that and a few articles I was able to establish I needed to open the ODBC Administrator from C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and not from the default in control panel.

Comment: Hey, between StackOverflow and (cough cough) Google, you can get almost anything figured out.

Answer (score 0):

solution found on this website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721702/windows-7-64-bit-odbc-drivers-for-ms-access-missing

It's likely the shortcut for setting ODBC data sources is pointing to the 32bit data sources instead of 64bit.

Go to control panel -> administrative tools --> select data sources(ODBC) --> then right click on that file --> go to properties --> in the shortcut tab -> change the path from %windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe to

%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

and make your connection. the driver for MS Access will work fine now.